# Control multiple column header formatting parameters xtable

Tags: r, latex, knitr, xtable

I have this example below where I create a basic data frame then output it to PDF through LaTeX using knitr. I am controlling some of the basic formatting and have used the function `bold` to bold the column headers and have redefined my column names through `colnames()`.

However, there is a function called `spaces` which on it's own will effectively remove spaces from the column headers. Is there a way to combine `bold` and `spaces` and pass it into `sanitize.colnames.function` to avoid renaming the column headers manually?

The intent is to basically manipulate the data frame in R to make it as dynamic as possible when data frames (printed to tables) change during analysis.

Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
%\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

hello here is a table - Table \ref{tab:mydataframe}

<<testtable, cache=FALSE, eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE, results = 'asis', warning=FALSE, error=FALSE, message=FALSE>>=

library(xtable)
library(printr)
library(knitr)
library(dplyr)

df_one = data.frame(column_one = c(1:10), column_two = c(11:20))

bold = function(x) {paste('{\\textbf{',x,'}}', sep ='')}
spaces = function(x){gsub("\\."," ",x)} # THIS IS NOT USED

colnames(df_one) = c('Column one', 'Column two')

print(xtable(df_one, type = 'latex', caption ='My test dataframe', label ='tab:mydataframe', align='lll', digits = 5), caption.placement ='top', include.rownames = FALSE, table.placement = '!h', sanitize.colnames.function = bold)
@
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Aneconomist - it should be `df_one` in the example above. It is just two columns with 1-10 and 11-20 as the entries. Really any data frame would work.

Comment: I was thinking about something like this: `mix = function(x){
  gsub("\\."," ",x)
  paste('{\\textbf{',x,'}}', sep ='')
}` And than just use it into `sanitize.colnames...` part.

Comment: @Aneconomist I had tried different variations of putting them into the same function in the same manner as you had outlined. However it would create spaces OR bold the wording, not both. If you got it to work with the example let me know.